# Windows 8 intermittent wifi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, router, wireless-router

I am using a hp spectrext ultrabook with windows 8 ,connected to a wifi router with wep encryption. The problem is that I am getting intermittent connection. i have even had my wireless nic card changed but the issue persists.

I am using a 2wire 2701hgv-e modem router. I don't think its a modem/router issue because I am getting intermittent connection elsewhere too.

How should I diagnose this problem??

Comment: does your wired connection also give you trouble ?

Comment: If you had your card changed, you probably did this already, but just in case: have you checked your network card drivers?

Comment: hi shakehar, wired connection is fine. ariane, what should i check for my network card driver?